# tmux session not resuming to the same from different entry points?

Tags: ssh, tmux

I don't know if this is supposed to work by default, but it seems like when I try to resume a tmux session I have from one machine or a different one. I am using two different kinds of connection to the tmux session, one from a Cygwin terminal versus another from an Ubuntu VM on the same computer. The sessions that are brought up are two different sessions. If I delete all windows in a session and disconnect from it, a brand new one is created instead of connecting to the existing one in the other method of connection. In both cases I connect via ssh to the same server, then run the `tmux` command below. I usually resume my session with this command:

```
tmux a -d || tmux
```

EDIT: I am disconnecting either with `Ctrl+a Ctrl+d` or simply by a disconnection in the network itself, but I can recover the connection afterwards if I do it with the same system I came from originally. If I list my session from Cygwin I get:

```
 tmux ls
0: 1 windows (created Wed Apr 17 15:49:23 2013) [149x45]
```

If I list it with the VM I get something different:

```
 tmux ls
0: 19 windows (created Thu Apr 11 09:24:00 2013) [191x35]
```

Any parameter I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a problem with sockets -- I suspect at some point you've created a brand new tmux listening on a different socket to your original one (perhaps perturbed via your shell when you've logged in?) and now have two tmux servers running.

Check /tmp (if this is where the tmux server creates its sockets) and you should be able to determine this, as well as the output from "ps aux".

Comment: how can I get rid of one of them and reconnect to the other?

Comment: You can't -- I mean, you should work out why the location of the socket creation changes, but see -S and -L to tmux to connect to a specific instance.  Are you saying then that you do have more than one socket created?

Answer (score 1):

You're not killing your to much session every time are you?  CTRL-A CTRL-D to detach from the session, rather than kill it.

When you are connected, list your tmux sessions with a `tmux ls`.  Make note of the first number from this command, that is what you will wan't to connect back to.  Then to connect to that session from either machine us a `tmux attach -t 0` assuming your tmux session is 0.